# Magento 2: Event-Observer for whenever the stock status of product changes

Tags: magento2, event-observer, stock

Is there an event for whenever a product goes from **In-Stock** to **Out of Stock** and vice-versa.

I basically need to programatically set the value of a custom product attribute depending on the stock status of a product.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `catalog_product_save_after, checkout_submit_all_after ,cataloginventory_stock_revert_products_sale, sales_order_item_cancel`(Depending ) and get the stock status. You can even check for that product attribute value is as desired out of stock and that out of stock do nothing else update the attribute value .

Put this `events.xml` in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\etc\`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And put your `Productsaveafter.php` in below path

app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Observer\

```
<?php

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct(); // you will get product object and you can check for stock and attribute values here

    }   
}
```

Comment: would product_save_after work when an In-stock product eventually sells out and become out of stock?

Comment: @Fokker i have updated events that you can use in answer